# ADCPi- how to run without being root?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a Pi Model A, running the latest version of Raspbian. Plugged into it is an ADC-Pi (https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/products/3/Raspberry-Pi/17/ADC-Pi-V2---Raspberry-Pi-Analogue-to-Digital-converter) with various analog sensors.

Running the demo code (which is below)
If I use './adc_demo.py' it works fine
If I use 'sudo python3 adc_demo.py' I get the error 'Import error: No module named quick2wire.i2c'.
What can I do so I can run it using the latter statement? I have another script that runs a motor through the GPIO pins on the pi, and that needs to be ran as root- and I'm trying to merge the two scripts together.

adc_demo.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# read abelectronics ADC Pi board inputs
# uses quick2wire from http://quick2wire.com/
# See http://elinux.org/RPi_ADC_I2C_Python for full setup instructions

import quick2wire.i2c as i2c

import re
import time

adc_address1 = 0x68
adc_address2 = 0x69

adc_channel1 = 0x98
adc_channel2 = 0xB8
adc_channel3 = 0xD8
adc_channel4 = 0xF8


for line in open('/proc/cpuinfo').readlines():
    m = re.match('(.*?)\s*:\s*(.*)', line)
    if m:
        (name, value) = (m.group(1), m.group(2))
        if name == "Revision":
           if value [-4:] in ('0002', '0003'):
                i2c_bus = 0
            else:
                i2c_bus = 1
            break

with i2c.I2CMaster(i2c_bus) as bus:

    def getadcreading(address, channel):
        bus.transaction(i2c.writing_bytes(address, channel))
        time.sleep(0.05)
        h, l, r = bus.transaction(i2c.reading(address,3))[0]
        time.sleep(0.05)
        h, l, r = bus.transaction(i2c.reading(address,3))[0]

        t = (h << 8) | l
        v = t * 0.000154
        if v < 5.5:
            return v
        else: # must be a floating input
            return 0.00

while True:

    print("1: %f" % getadcreading(adc_address1, adc_channel1))
    print("2: %f" % getadcreading(adc_address1, adc_channel2))
    print("3: %f" % getadcreading(adc_address1, adc_channel3))
    print("4: %f" % getadcreading(adc_address1, adc_channel4))

    print("5: %f" % getadcreading(adc_address2, adc_channel1))
    print("6: %f" % getadcreading(adc_address2, adc_channel2))
    print("7: %f" % getadcreading(adc_address2, adc_channel3))
    print("8: %f" % getadcreading(adc_address2, adc_channel4))

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: it is not in your root PYTHONPATH

Comment: How did you install the `quick2wire` module? Are you using different python versions for your root / user?

Comment: add `Defaults env_keep += PYTHONPATH` to `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: I installed quick2wire following these instructions: http://elinux.org/RPi_ADC_I2C_Python

Comment: @UglyTeapot, have you added to `/etc/sudoers` as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, but seem to have broken sudoers as a consequence... it now has a parse error (I probably typoed)... which makes the file impossible to open and fix over ssh...

Comment: Ok, fixed that! And that now appears to work! I'd never even heard of the sudoers file, thank you!